# how to use vue-3-socket.io with composition api in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

how can i access the socket instance inside the setup function in `vue.js` component

i use `vue-3-socket.io`

in my `main.js`

```
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-3-socket.io'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: SocketIO('http://metinseylan.com:1992', {}), 
    vuex: {
      store,
      actionPrefix: "SOCKET_",
      mutationPrefix: "SOCKET_"
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a composable per se. You could use `this.$socket` with options API tho.

Comment: i think this page might help https://github.com/modex98/test-relabs/blob/master/src/components/EventsTable.vue

Answer (score 6):

I will use socket.io directly, without Vue Plugin:

```js
export const useSocketIO = () => {
    const socket = io('http://metinseylan.com:1992')
    return {
        socket,
    }
}
```

`Component`

```html
<script setup>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

const { socket } = useSocketIO()
socket.on('welcome', () => { console.log('welcome') })
  
</script>
```

Comment: Will this also disconnected the socket properly or will it only register on the server side after the next ping runs out?

Comment: How would that look, on beforeUnmount?

Answer (score 4):

I first used the answer by @kissu (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400545/3475778)  but I found this problematic as it creates multiple socketIO connections which is not what you want (e.g. send to everyone except the sender will not work as expected because you will receive the message via the other connections of our client)

My approach now is creating an object of the class and import the object instead of the class itself.

`src/services/socketio.service.ts`

```js
import type { Socket } from "socket.io-client";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import type { ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents } from "../communication";

class SocketIOService {
  socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents>;
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(process.env.VUE_APP_SOCKET_ENDPOINT || "http://localhost:3000" );
  }
}

// create an instance/connection here
export const socket = new SocketIOService().socket;
```

`src/components/myButton.vue`

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
// import the object instead of the class
import { socket } from "../services/socketio.service";

async function buttonPress() {
  socket.emit("buttonPressed");
}
</script>
```

Multiple components will now share the same socketio connection :)

Comment: whereis the best place to add once authentication or token ? const socket = io(URL, {authorization: {token:'test'}), I used it but server do not see it.