# Can't establish connection between VueJS 3 and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sockets, socket.io, vuejs3

I am completely new to Socket.IO and generally to Back-end technologies. However, I have experience with Vue and I am trying to create a simple multiplayer game.

But I am stuck on the first step... connecting vueJS and SocketIO.

Here is the server:

```
const app = express()
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = require('socket.io')(8000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection');

  socket.on('updateUsers', function(data) {
    console.log('event received');
  });
})
```

This is the main.js:

```
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import SocketIO from "socket.io-client"

import "./assets/main.css";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router, new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: SocketIO('http://localhost:5173/'), 
    }));

app.mount("#app");
```

And the homepage.vue:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
data() {
    return {
      socket: io()
    }
  },
methods: {
    startGame() {this.socket.emit('updateUsers', "someUser")
    },
}
```

So neither the "new connection" from the server is rendered in the terminal, nor the front-end is able to send events(no errors, but also nothing happens)
Do you see anything wrong? Could it be something with the router or because I pass two arguments to the app?

```
app.use(router, new VueSocketIO...)
```

Comment: Are you passing in port 8000 in your backend for the server? Because your `main.js` is reaching out to `localhost:5173`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466297/how-to-use-vue-3-socket-io-with-composition-api-in-vue-js/72400545#72400545 this answer can help you ?

Comment: @cpppatrick I've been playing around with the ports. And today I actually managed to get it to a state where it connects to the server, but drops the connection immediately. And that's the error in the console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OI51KoF. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:8000’)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and it's almost stupid. The socket library doesn't support VueJS 3, it supports only vueJS 2. So there are 2 alternatives to get this working, the first is [Vue-3-Socket.io](https://github.com/kil0ba/Vue-3-Socket.io) and the second is this alpha version of [Vue-Socket.io-Extended](https://github.com/probil/vue-socket.io-extended/tree/alpha). I went for the second one and it gets the work done.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add this express middleware code to allow cross origin request in the Socket IO Server.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next()
})
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I will try it tomorrow :)

Comment: Added it, but again nothing. I forgot to share the error in the console, which is: `Uncaught TypeError: t3.prototype is undefined - vue-socketio.js:10:13994`